# Can I substitute amaretto syrup for amaretto liqueur?

Tags: substitutions

I have a recipe that calls for 1/2 cup amaretto liqueur.  Can I substitute Torani amaretto syrup and should I use the same amount - 1/2 cup?

Answer (score 3):

no not at all. alcohol in recipes is generally there because certain flavor compounds are only soluble in alcohol. adding a half cup of syrup will make your recipe come out much much sweeter than it should. A better substitution would be probably around a teaspoon of almond extract and some neutral liquor like vodka. It would also be helpful if you include what recipe you are using or what you are attempting to make.

Comment: It is a cake loaf recipe.  I would prefer not to use any liqueur in it...could I do some combination of the syrup and water?

Comment: I would hesitate about using syrup unless you remove some of the sugar in the recipe. If you're concerned about using alcohol you can use some almond extract and water